# Wordpress adding extra day

Tags: php, date, datetime

The code below is meant to look for day 5 (friday) and day 6 (saturday) for the next 3 weeks before it does a custom wordpress query. For some reason i just can't get it to add day 6.

Any ideas please?

```
/* We need this to start on a Friday */

$datDate = date( 'Y-m-d' );

while( date('w', strtotime( $datDate ) ) != 5 ) {

    $datDate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $datDate . " +1 DAY" ) );

}

/* This is over 3 weeks, so we need 3 arrays of all available days */

$arrDate1[] = "'".$datDate . " 00:00:00'";

for( $i = 1; $i < 7; $i++ ) {

    $datDate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $datDate . " +1 DAY" ) );

    $arrDate1[] = "'".$datDate ." 00:00:00'";

}

/* Ok, create a new array and add another 7 days */

for( $i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++ ) {

    $datDate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $datDate . " +1 DAY" ) );

    $arrDate2[] = "'".$datDate . " 00:00:00'";

}

/* Same again for our third array */

for( $i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++ ) {

    $datDate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $datDate . " +1 DAY" ) );

    $arrDate3[] = "'".$datDate . " 00:00:00'";

}



/* Convert our 3 dates to comma seperates strings for the IN QUERY */

$strDate1 = implode(",",$arrDate1);

$strDate2 = implode(",",$arrDate2);

$strDate3 = implode(",",$arrDate3);


$strQuery = "
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop is missing the `=` in `<=`:

```
for( $i = 1; $i < 7; $i++ ) {
```

should be

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++ ) {
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: If it's not what you mean, can you give an example of what you expect `$arrDate1`, `$arrDate2` and `$arrDate3` to contain if you ran this today (August 13 2013)?  There may be a more efficient way to get the result you're after.